# Respond with HTTP 404 to every request not in URI whitelist with Apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I am attempting to redirect to a static `404.html` page if the request URI does not match what is in my whitelist. At the moment that is just `/golf`, to keep things simple.

This is my Apache vhosts config:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/crmpicco/wordpress"
ServerName crmpicco.localhost:443
ServerAlias www.crmpicco.localhost
ServerAdmin crmpicco@crmpicco.co.uk
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/crmpicco.localhost.error_log"
TransferLog "/private/var/log/apache2/crmpicco.localhost.access_log"
ErrorDocument 404 404.html

<Directory "/var/www/crmpicco/wordpress/">
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options -Indexes
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride all

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/golf
        RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
</Directory>
```

I have the `mod_rewrite` Apache module loaded and, of course, have restarted Apache after adding the RewriteRule.

What am I missing? At the moment it's just hitting the 404 script inside my theme which is being handled by Wordpress - not Apache.

**EDIT:** Trying to track down the root cause.

When I look for the `httpd-ssl.conf` on my machine I get multiple copies.

```
$ locate httpd-ssl.conf
/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf.mojave
/private/etc/apache2/original/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
/usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.35/.bottle/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
/usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.35/.bottle/etc/httpd/original/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
/usr/local/etc/httpd/original/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

`apachectl` appears to be pointing to a config that is not in use!

```
$ apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  crmpicco.localhost (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:121)
ServerRoot: "/usr/local/opt/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/var/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/usr/local/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="_www" id=70 not_used
Group: name="_www" id=70 not_used
```

The `/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` file was the config file I have been editing above to add the RewriteRules, however this appears to have had no effect.

I note that when I disable the `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf` file it breaks my Apache config and the pages don't load, so it appears like that's the file being used - however why does `apachectl` report a different file?!

Comment: Move the redirect rewrite rule for golf above the wordpress rules and try it.

Comment: @PanamaJack Thanks for your comment. I moved the three lines above the start of the Wordpress lines (beginning with `Options`) but it has had no effect.

Comment: Is this the only `VirtualHost` in your configuration? Are you using `https://crmpicco.localhost:443/something` to test this?

Comment: @DusanBajic Hi. Yes, this is the only `VirtualHost` in my config. I am hitting it with `https://crmpicco.localhost/crmpicco` (no need to specify the port). I've had a look around but I can't find a sure fire way of handling Wordpress 404s with Apache. Should this work in your opinion?

Comment: It should work. Can you try (just for test) putting `RewriteRule ^ - [F]` immediately below `RewriteEngine On`, to see if it will block all requests

Comment: @DusanBajic Hmmm, thanks - but this is not blocking all requests and clearly it should. I have installed Apache with Homebrew and I am restarting it with `brew services restart httpd`. Should that be blocking all requests?

Comment: Yes, it should. Can you edit your post and provide full VirtualHost config?

Comment: @DusanBajic I have updated my question with further information. It appears I have some sort of mis-match or duplication in my Apache config. Around 6 months ago I installed Apache with Homebrew because the macOS updates had a habit of trashing my Apache config with every major upgrade. I know other developers who have resorted to using Apache through Homebrew to circumvent this. It would appear this config issue is causing me some problems here - can you see where this has gone wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195849/discussion-between-dusan-bajic-and-crmpicco).